# when i do a simple program with Neo4j java api , i get the following error

Tags: java, api, neo4j

1. My java version:java version "1.8.0_25"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
2. My Neo4j version: neo4j-community-2.3.0-RC1
3. I imported all jar files in 'neo4j-community-2.3.0-RC1\lib' direcory to classpath with Eclipse
4. I can find the messages.log file in "C:/TPNeo4jDB", the log is: 
   `2015-10-15 06:19:03.151+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityFacadeFactory] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'`
5. I use windows 8 now

When my program runs 
`GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");`

I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityEditionModule.determineEdition(CommunityEditionModule.java:142)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityEditionModule.publishEditionInfo(CommunityEditionModule.java:132)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityEditionModule.(CommunityEditionModule.java:122)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.createEdition(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:50)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:125)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:129)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:117)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:185)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:79)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:74)
at com.gongjiaolaile.view.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Comment: Poor formatting of the problem. Barely readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are missing some libraries. First of all there are several places in Neo4j directory with libraries:

- `lib/`
- `system/lib/`

Second one - you should use build management tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

In Neo4j documentation there is [Using Neo4j embedded in Java applications](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html) section, that gives you overview how to use Neo4j. And [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html#_add_neo4j_as_a_dependency) is described how to add Neo4j as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same problem in Tutorialspoint's "Learn Neo4j" examples.

GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");

**From Neo4j document.**

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory.html

Use newEmbeddedDatabase(**File**) or newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(File) to create a database instance.

newEmbeddedDatabase takes File as parameter.

The example codes,

GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");

pass string instead of File as parameter.

**Try this**

File f = new File("C:/TPNeo4jDB");

GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(f);

It solves the problem for me but I am using Mac.